# FTP LOGIN Issue in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ftp

I am trying to connect to FTP client using java. My code is here

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(url);
boolean login = ftpClient.login(user, pwd);
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

It is working on my local, but when I run on AWS server is throws following issue.

```
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:317)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:294)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:483)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:608)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:582)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.quit(FTP.java:864)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.logout(FTPClient.java:1109)
at dashboard.utils.DownloadDataFeed.cjAutomation(DownloadDataFeed.java:441)
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading apache.commons dependencies might solve this

Comment: did not solve the issue, for now I am using python for ftp download, and  its working